# How are the subversion hook templates generated for each repository?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, subversion-edge

We are using Subversion Edge 5.2 on Windows.

Whenever we create a repo, a hooks folder within the repo is pre-populated with the following templates:

1. post-commit.tmpl
2. post-lock.tmpl
3. post-revprop-change.tmpl
4. post-unlock.tmpl
5. pre-commit.tmpl
6. pre-lock.tmpl
7. pre-revprop-change.tmpl
8. pre-unlock.tmpl
9. start-commit.tmpl

Where are the master copies kept? I want to override post-commit.tmpl so whenever we create a new repo it uses our version, it saves us the manual step of going to the folder and replacing the file manually.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a misunderstanding:
These hooks are examples and templates (.tmpl). 
They are not runnable so even if you modify them, you need to make them executable. So a manual step is still necessary.

They are defined directly in SVN Source code:
[Link to repos.c](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/repos.c) (search for "/* Start-commit hook. */")

So unfortunately you cannot change the default hook templates(unless you want to patch svn sourcecode and build it yourself..)

Comment: I do understand that they are templates/examples. To clarify, I was hoping to be able to override the creation of post-commit.tmpl and instead use the post-commit.bat that we got working. Since the folder and templates are being generated from code this is obviously not possible unless I am willing to patch SVN.

Thanks!